# How to find number of lines of a file which is in perforce?

Tags: perforce

I am using **`p4 print <filename> | wc -l`** to find number of lines. But this is consuming more time. Is there any better way?

Comment: Note that if you don't use `p4 print -q`, you'll be counting the extra line that `p4` adds listing the filename and revision.  That said, numbers of lines are rarely useful metrics...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line count of a file is not stored in the Perforce metadata, so fetching the actual content and counting the lines yourself is indeed the best way.

If you're trying to gather metrics and are okay with a rougher approximation in exchange for quicker queries, the file size *is* cached -- you can access it with `p4 fstat` or `p4 sizes`.